# Incorrect username / password message and redirect

Tags: php, html, authentication, passwords

Creating a Client Login area. I have my log in form in a clientLogin.html:

```
       <form name="ClientLogin" method="post" action="login.php"> <br>
            <p>
             <label for='Username'>Username</label> <br>
            <input type="text" name="username" />
            </p>
            <p>

            <label for='Password'>Password</label> <br>
            <input type="password" name="password" />
            </p>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

        </form>
```

If the username & password combination are incorrect I want to redirect to this page adding a message saying "incorrect username/ password please try again". This is the code from login.php:

```
<?php


//Connect to the database
    require('db.php');

    $user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
    $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);

    $clientdata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username='$user' and            password='$pass'")
    or die (mysql_error());

    $data = mysql_fetch_array($clientdata, MYSQL_ASSOC);

    if(mysql_num_rows($clientdata) == 1){

session_start();


$_SESSION['username'] = $user;


header('Location: profile.php');

    }else{
header('Location: clientLogin.html');
    }
```

I expect the clientLogin.html files needs changing to a .php file. other than that I am stumped. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What error are you getting? Other than the first line which should start with `//` since that's a comment

Comment: You could use something to the affect of 

`if(($user["user"] == $login["user"]) && ($user["pass"] == $login["pass"])) { echo "You are logged in"; } else{ echo "You are not logged in";`

Comment: @Fred-ii- numRow is also a good solution

Comment: @FaceOfJock Yes indeed, you're right. I only provided the OP a quick example that I have on file.

Comment: We need more details about error because i think this code is correct

Comment: And now for the almighty question: "What have you tried?" ;-)

Comment: @FaceOfJock Hi, thanks for all your super quick input! The code I have shown does work, what I want is additional code so that when I redirect back to clientLogin.html after a failed login attempt a message is added on the page saying "incorrect username/ password please try again".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change extension of  clientLogin.html from `.html` to `.php`

Change `header('Location: clientLogin.html');` to `header('Location: clientLogin.php');`

Add this part of code at the top of your `clientLogin.php` page:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
 echo 'incorrect username/ password please try again.' ;
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi, Sorry I think I have confused matters, I have just edited the original question as the redirect currently goes back to the clientLogin.html, there is no clientlogin.php.

Comment: Hi, sorry I'm quite new to this! I have used your solution 2, copied the code into the file now called clientLogin.php, but now the first time you visit the page to log in the error message comes up, I only want it to come up after a failed login attempt.

Comment: @SJBenton , create a file clientLogin.html ,put the html code in the first solution , that's all

Comment: That way would produce a static message, what I want is to go back to the original form (clientlogin.php) so they can try again, with a message appearing on this page, saying that the details they entered the first time were incorrect.

Comment: ah sorry , i tought they are different pages , so now , you need to change extension to .php and also in header location ,and places the code i will give at the top of your file , check my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can set a SESSION flag and when calling ClientLogin.

```
    $_SESSION['loginerror'] = 1;
```

in ClientLogin.php

```
    if ($_SESSION['loginerror'] > 0) {
      /* Display Appropriate Error message */
    }
```

Comment: so the top bit goes in login.php inside else{  and the second bit goes in what was clientLogin.html (now clientLogin.php) like this <?php if ($_SESSION['loginerror'] > 0) {echo "incorrect login details";}?>

Answer (score -1):

you should use exit(); after redirecting to other file like..

```
header('Location: profile.php');
exit();
```

you please use `mysqli` instead of `mysql` .its not going to be supported by 
new version of php.

Comment: ClientLogin is name of form

Comment: @ClientLogin yes but this is not the problem

Comment: @RajeevRanjan Changing the OP's file extension to `.php` doesn't explain what is required in order for it to work properly. Your answer does not answer nor explain these details.