# Reload login screen with error message after incorrect credentials entered

Tags: php

I'm having an issue with some code I am trying to change.  Ignore the blatant security issues in the code, i'm not using a database in this exercise.

Basically, I need to display an incorrect credential error message if the user inputs the wrong user/password.  I cannot figure out how to do this.  I have got it so it redirects back to the login page but I cannot get an messages to appear on that page.

The code is as follows:

Form on login.php

```
<form action="login2.php" method="post">

      <p>Username: <input type="text" name="username" /></p>

      <p>Password: <input type="password" name="password" /></p>

      <p><input type="submit" value="Login" name ="sub" /> </p>

</form>
```

PHP on login2.php

```
<?php

  session_start();

 // Checks the input from login.php

   if(isset($_POST['sub'])){

        $username = $_POST['username']; $password = $_POST['password'];

   if($username === 'test' && $password === 'pass'){

        $_SESSION['userid'] = true; header("Location: index.php"); die();

    }

        else 

    if($username !== 'admin' or $password !== 'password')$userError = 'Invalid credentials';

    {

        echo "Wrong username or password";

           $_SESSION["loginerror"] = 1;

        header("Location:login.php");

    }

 }    

// Allows ANY input to trigger access to the main site
?>
```

I've looked at the solutions on this question, but they dont seem to work:
  [Incorrect username / password message and redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18814483/incorrect-username-password-message-and-redirect)

Answer (score -1):

Just add a text field at top of the form :

```
<p <?php if ($_SESSION["loginerror"] == 1 ){echo 'style="display: none;";} ?> > Invalid user/login</p>
```

Comment: Did you test this? `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '>' in /path/to/file.php on line 1`

Comment: I have tried this but it displays the error message constantly even when i first load up the page.